# Upper and lower limit Calculus problem.

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

In the book which I am reading/understanding, there is an integral(actually it is part of gauss' divergence theorem proof),

$
  \int_{f_1(x,y)}^{f_2(x,y)}\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}\;dz
$

Now, they have solved it this way,

$
 =F_3\{x,y,f_2(x,y)\}-F_3\{x,y,f_1(x,y)\}\;\;-(i)
$

Now, I am not able to understand how they did it. Till, now, I have learnt to directly put the upper end and lower limit.
For example,

$
  \quad \vert x\vert_1^2 = 2-1;\;\;-(ii)
$

But, in the above case eq(i), they have somewhat not proceeded like eq(ii),
Now can anyone please explain what exactly is happening?

Comment: Well $F_3 = F_3(x, y, z)$ and we are only interested in the $z$ component. If you look we are only integrating over $z$, thus we only replace the z part when inserting our limits. Does that make sense?

Comment: can u elaborate more?

Comment: $\int_{z = f_1(x,y)}^{z =f_2(x,y)} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} F_3(x,y,z) \,\mathrm{d}z = F_3(x,y,z) \mid_{z = f_1(x,y)}^{z =f_2(x,y)} = F_3(x, y, f_2(x,y) ) - F_3(x, y, f_1(x,y) )$

Comment: why is  $F_3$ not being eliminated like $x$ in $eq(ii)$ ?

Comment: Because we are integrating with respect to $z$ and not $F_3$. If we had something like $\int_0^1 F_3 \,\mathrm{d}F_3 = \frac{1}{2}F_3\mid_0^1 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 - \frac{1}{2} \cdot 0 = \frac{1}{2}$, then $F_3$ would "vanish". Due note that this is clear missuse of notation. You could try with an example. Let $F_3(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z$, and try to perform the integration, what happens?

Comment: oh i get it !....